# Make fails to build FreeImage - when building OpenCascade

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, compilation, msys2, opencascade

I have succesfully used CMake. Then i use MSYS2, to traverse inside the BUILD directory and i type `make`.
The build goes well but when it scans dependencies for FreeImage - then it fails.

This is the compiler i have:

```
User1@User1-PC MSYS ~
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And now the warning - errors. I have a different code block for all the different objects that `make` has complains. The final one will also contain the error message.

OBJECT 1:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/__/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp.obj
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp: In function 'FIMULTIBITMAP* FreeImage_OpenMultiBitmap(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT, const char*, BOOL, BOOL, BOOL, int)':
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:254:10: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     std::auto_ptr<FreeImageIO> io (new FreeImageIO);
          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:265:10: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     std::auto_ptr<FIMULTIBITMAP> bitmap (new FIMULTIBITMAP);
          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:266:10: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     std::auto_ptr<MULTIBITMAPHEADER> header (new MULTIBITMAPHEADER);
          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:299:11: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      std::auto_ptr<CacheFile> cache_file (new CacheFile(cache_name, keep_cache_in_memory));
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp: In function 'FIMULTIBITMAP* FreeImage_OpenMultiBitmapFromHandle(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT, FreeImageIO*, fi_handle, int)':
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:339:11: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      std::auto_ptr<FIMULTIBITMAP> bitmap (new FIMULTIBITMAP);
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:340:11: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      std::auto_ptr<MULTIBITMAPHEADER> header (new MULTIBITMAPHEADER);
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:341:11: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      std::auto_ptr<FreeImageIO> tmp_io (new FreeImageIO (*io));
           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:367:12: warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       std::auto_ptr<CacheFile> cache_file (new CacheFile("", TRUE));
            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/memory:80,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:53,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/CacheFile.h:28,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/MultiPage.cpp:33:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/unique_ptr.h:53:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
```

OBJECT2:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/__/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/Plugin.cpp.obj
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/Plugin.cpp: In function 'void FreeImage_Initialise(BOOL)':
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/Plugin.cpp:314:15: warning: 'char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)' specified bound 460 equals destination size [-Wstringop-overflow=]
        strncat(buffer, find_data.name, MAX_PATH + 200);
        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

OBJECT 3:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/__/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginEXR.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfHeader.h:51,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/IlmImf/ImfOutputFile.h:46,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginEXR.cpp:33:
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:228:34: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     const Vec2 & normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                  ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:232:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     Vec2<T>  normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:440:34: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     const Vec3 & normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                  ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:444:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     Vec3<T>  normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:622:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     const Vec4 &    normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:626:44: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
     Vec4<T>         normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                            ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:714:30: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<short>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                              ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:723:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<short>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:738:28: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<int>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                            ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:747:35: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<int>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                   ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:762:30: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<short>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                              ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:771:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<short>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:786:28: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<int>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                            ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:795:35: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<int>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                   ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:809:30: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<short>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                              ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:818:37: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<short>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                     ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:833:28: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<int>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                            ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:842:35: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<int>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc);
                                   ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:1212:26: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<T>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                          ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:1249:33: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec2<T>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                                 ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:1704:26: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<T>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                          ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:1743:33: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec3<T>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                                 ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:2109:26: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<T>::normalizeExc () throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                          ^~~~~
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathVec.h:2150:33: warning: dynamic exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 [-Wdeprecated]
 Vec4<T>::normalizedExc () const throw (IEX_NAMESPACE::MathExc)
                                 ^~~~~
```

FINAL OBJECT AND ERROR FROM MAKE:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/__/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginG3.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/LibTIFF4/tiffio.h:258,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/LibTIFF4/tiffiop.h:60,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginG3.cpp:23:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:735:23: error: conflicting declaration of 'int _snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)' with 'C' linkage
   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _snprintf(char * __restrict__ _Dest,size_t _Count,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
                       ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/LibTIFF4/tiffiop.h:33,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginG3.cpp:23:
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/LibTIFF4/tif_config.h:84:18: note: previous declaration with 'C++' linkage
 #define snprintf _snprintf
                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6361,
                 from C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/Utilities.h:44,
                 from C:/Users/User1/Desktop/OPENCAS/oce/oce-win-bundle/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginG3.cpp:26:
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:175:11: error: '::snprintf' has not been declared
   using ::snprintf;
           ^~~~~~~~
C:/mingw-w64-10.2/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdio:185:22: error: '__gnu_cxx::snprintf' has not been declared
   using ::__gnu_cxx::snprintf;
                      ^~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/build.make:1021: oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/__/libs/FreeImage/Source/FreeImage/PluginG3.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2621: oce-win-bundle/FreeImage.cmake/CMakeFiles/FreeImage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2
```

Comment: For OCE I use g++ 5.2 here, although I have a newer g++ installed. In do not exactly remember the reason, but probably there was a build error with the newer version. Perhaps even the one that you show here. Note that the deprecation warnings do not hinder the compilation. Only the `::snprintf` error is a real problem. The reason for such major compilation problems is that OCE is not well maintained. You could try to use an older compiler or you could try to fix the FreeImage sources...

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Thank you for the help! But since i have gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0, how can i roll back to 5.2? You said you have insatlled a newer compiler, so how are you ablet o use 5.2?

Comment: You could build it yourself: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/. It is not too hard, I could post the commands here. But before doing that I would consider using the official OCCT. Then at least you have the most modern version of Open CASCADE (and the fastest one). Still, it could be that the software you want to use, which has been designed for OCE does not work with the current OCCT. But I myself would prefer updating that code to a modern Open CASCADE instead of struggling with "ancient" code.

Comment: Another, perhaps even better way would be to download the 3rd party libraries from here: https://www.opencascade.com/content/3rd-party-components (if you scroll to the right, there are MinGw downloads) and try to adapt OCE build to use the already existing libraries instead of building them. But I don't know whether that is easy or not.

Comment: I actually asked the author of that software if i should use the newest version and he said  "I don't know for sure, but I'd be surprised if it did, because an executable doesn't usually come with all the development files needed to compile against a library (header files, shared libraries). " Of course i could as well try.

Comment: Ahh, is it a binary program? Then you will need the exact OCE/OCCT version!

Comment: I don't even know how to do the second approach. I think that since i already have devoted time i should at least try to build it myself. So, i need somehow to get g++ 5.2 and hope for the best right?

Comment: Is converting STEP files to STL files all you want to do? You need about twenty lines of code to achieve that. In this case I would propose to get the newest OCCT, compile it (you probably already know how) and then write the conversion code yourself (you can "steal" the idea from `lib.cpp` of the conversion program you mentioned).

Comment: Yes this is all i want. I want to run it from node though, but the author has provide a solution to that ("Run make lib to create the dynamic library and ffi file for use in node.js."). Can i find documentation online for OCC? I browsed this https://www.opencascade.com/content/documentation and said contact us. If i login, can i see documentation?

Comment: BTW, i saw this on the OCC forums https://www.opencascade.com/content/unable-convert-step-file-stl-file. It says it uses openCascade 7.2.0. So if i download and install the newest version of OCC, will this code work? So i can save some time.

Comment: Just click onto the "latest certified release" link to see the documentation. OCE is just a fork of OCCT, so actually they behave very similar when reading and writing files. Regarding the forum post: probably you could also use the newest OCCT version, since reading and writing files has not changed much/at all? as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know the differences between oce and occt. You suggest i signup to the website and download the latest exe am i correct? And then try to compile somehing similar as this man has, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, at least this is what I would do.

Comment: I installed OCCT and at first i copied the guys code in the forum, to see if i can replicate his errors. But i got this instead "testCode.c:2:10: fatal error: STEPControl_Reader.hxx: No such file or directory
 #include "STEPControl_Reader.hxx"". The program cannot find the header file although i installed OCCT. How does the program knows where to look for headers? How can i make the program find the headers that i specified (and i assume are installed when i installed OCCT)?

Comment: You need to tell the compiler the include paths using `-I` or `-isystem`, the library paths using `-L` and the libraries using `-l` or setup a build system that cares for that.

Comment: Comparing the two programs - the one on the OCCT forum and step2stl, they look similar. Since step2stl works (without taking into consideration the version of OCCT), i would like to execute that, now that i have OCCT installed and see what errors it generates, so i can see what to change. Do you happen to know how i can compile it, since you are a Windows user of OCCT? I have tried many different things, and now i am confused. The installation directory has many folder which contain  libs, bins and includes. However, step2stl only uses header files that exist in one directory in my system.

Comment: The linker will tell you which methods are missing, if you have forgotten a necessary library. Use the method name to search or guess the missing library.